# Django. Query array params

Tags: django, rest

I have view `generics.ListCreateAPIView` and this view has `filter_fields` like `groups`

```
filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,
filter_fields = ('groups',
```

On the URL i can get list of groups like this:

`users/?groups=1&groups=2&groups=3`

But in the Front-End programmer can create GET link like this(with []):

`users/?groups[]=1&groups[]=2&groups[]=3`

If Django will has link like this `users/?groups[]=1&groups[]=2&groups[]=3` filters will not works.

My question is, what settings need to do for django project for link like this: `users/?groups[]=1&groups[]=2&groups[]=3` ?

Comment: Why does the front-end dev want to do that? Tell them not to.